# How to enable ssl in jetty 9.3.12?

Tags: ssl, https, jetty

I am following these tutorial but didn't work.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL
Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Whenever i tried to enable ssl module anywhere in jetty then jetty gives an error when i try to restart it after modification.

Comment: You can edit your question to modify it. Please describe, in detail, what you have tried.  (also, `wiki.eclipse.org` is for older versions of Jetty.  See the giant red banner at the top)